# indexing matrix computation by lists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a list of triangles stored as indices into a list of vertices:

```
faces = {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 3}, {7, 8, 9}, {8, 10, 11}, {2, 1, 
  12}, {10, 8, 13} ...
```

and a list of interior angles of each triangle

I wrote the procedural code below to compute the cotan Laplacian. My question is: Can this be done more efficiently and more elegantly with list-based or other constructs?

```
cotanLaplacian = SparseArray[{1, 1} -> 0, {numV, numV}];

For[i = 1, i <= Length[faces], i++,

 cotans = Cot[angles[[i]]];


 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 1]], faces[[i, 2]]]] += cotans[[3]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 2]], faces[[i, 1]]]] += cotans[[3]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 1]], faces[[i, 1]]]] -= cotans[[3]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 2]], faces[[i, 2]]]] -= cotans[[3]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 2]], faces[[i, 3]]]] += cotans[[1]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 3]], faces[[i, 2]]]] += cotans[[1]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 2]], faces[[i, 2]]]] -= cotans[[1]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 3]], faces[[i, 3]]]] -= cotans[[1]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 3]], faces[[i, 1]]]] += cotans[[2]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 1]], faces[[i, 3]]]] += cotans[[2]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 3]], faces[[i, 3]]]] -= cotans[[2]];

 cotanLaplacian[[faces[[i, 1]], faces[[i, 1]]]] -= cotans[[2]];

 ]
```

Comment: Look like `GraphicsComplex`.Provide all of your `face` and your coordinate of vertices